# How do I find lines of code using semgrep CLI?

Tags: semgrep

I've run semgrep scan from the CLI (installed through python pip) and it doesn't report on the lines of code. Can it report on lines of code in the repository?

It only listed the number of files, number of rules per language, and the issues it's found.